# WCF Service returning Dataser very slow with basicHttpBinding

Tags: wcf

I am working on WCf library that is hosted on IIS.
It is working fine but it is very slow while returning Dataset.
I hear about BinaryFormatter Serialize but it is not working at my end.
so please any one give me brief about how to return dataset more officienty using WCF services.
Thanks in advance.